# How to do an internal redirect with CodeIgniter for robots.txt?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I have a server running Apache 2.2.24 and CodeIgniter 2.1.0 .

I want to handle requests for `/robots.txt` dynamically, using CodeIgniter, but the only solution I have found so far is to use .htaccess to issue a temporary redirect that tells clients to fetch `/robots_txt` instead (**note the underscore**).

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_txt [NC,L,R=307]
```

Later in the .htaccess there are these rules for CodeIgniter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

Within CodeIgniter I can route requests for `robots_txt` to a controller.

My question is, how can I change this to an internal redirect? That is, when I get a request for `robots.txt`, instead of issuing a redirect response to the client, how can I rewrite the url to handle it internally as `robots_txt`?

Anything I have tried leads to a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid a full redirect just do it as follows:

```
# rewrite robots.txt to index.php
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ index.php?/$0 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Then within CodeIgniter you can route requests for `robots.txt` (no underscore here) to a controller.

Comment: I did not need any RewriteRule for robots. All I needed was to set up the route for robots.txt in CodeIgniter. Thank you!